# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, variables, highcharts, scope

When I change minmax by clicking on `Change MinMax of Chart1` button, sets chart1 extremes with the new passed in values. Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/we8Lh0rx/23/

This fiddle has no issues accessing chartEp0,chartEp1 or chartEp2  while setting MinMax. Below is how chart variables are declared here.

```
     var chartEp0, chartEp1, chartEp2;
 
     //chart1
     chartEp0 = Highcharts.chart('chart1', {});
```

Refactored the code (to make it more maintainable). Now I get error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` for chartEp0, when I click on `Change MinMax of Chart1`. Please find the refactored code which has issue: https://jsfiddle.net/v5fphnwd/47/

Below is how chart variables are declared now.

```
create() {
  const highchart = Highcharts.chart(this.container, {}
}

const chartEp0 = new Chart(chart1,  1, 'NorthAmerica1', data);
chartEp0.create();
```

Believe `chartEp0` is not in the scope of SetMinMax for it to be used. How can I fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `chartEp0` is an object created based on `Chart` class, not on `Highchcharts.chart` and there is no `yAxis` property. You can for example store the created chart and refer to it by `chartEp0.chart`.

```
class Chart {
  ...
  create() {
    this.chart = Highcharts.chart(this.container, {
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

---

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gt0wy3q1/